# can any explain me the following piece of code

Tags: java, applet

can anyone explain how we get the following output in applet class output
initializing ... satrting...stopping...starting...stopping...starting
i found the code from the following link 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html

```
StringBuffer buffer;

public void init() {
    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    addItem("initializing... ");
}

public void start() {
    addItem("starting... ");
}

public void stop() {
    addItem("stopping... ");
}

public void destroy() {
    addItem("preparing for unloading...");
}

private void addItem(String newWord) {
    System.out.println(newWord);
    buffer.append(newWord);
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
//Draw a Rectangle around the applet's display area.
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 
       getWidth() - 1,
       getHeight() - 1);

//Draw the current string inside the rectangle.
    g.drawString(buffer.toString(), 5, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, the image start and stop will be called based on the activity of the applet.  Any time it is "***idle***" (by minimizing your applet viewer screen) it will stop().  Then, when it becomes "***active***" (by maximizing your applet viewer screen), it will start() again:

[image]

from this site [here](http://www.rohanchaubey.com/2014/09/applet-and-graphics-programming-in-java.html)